# Can I Download (Dump) kernel image (and full ROM) on Intel device?

Tags: rom-flashing, rom

I need to download the ROM from an Intel device, and I can't unlock the bootloader.

I know that there are tools to do so on Meditek devices, that let you access the device before it boots to the bootloader. An example is the Wwr_MTK Tool together with SP Flash Tool. (See my post at [Backup/dump kernel image (and full ROM) without root for Mediatek Devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203283/backup-dump-kernel-image-and-full-rom-without-root-for-mediatek-devices)).
I'm looking for a similar thing for Intel devices. This should let me download the ROM without having to use Fastboot.

P.S. If you have any other suggestions on being able to download the ROM I would appreciate it.

Comment: The reason that it's possible on MTK device's is because of a bootloader before the bootloader... You can access the CPU firmware via the USB port, this gives you unrestricted access to storage regions and allows you to create an image of the partitions or entire regions. Intel does have the same bootloader before the bootloader, however getting a driver that works seems to be a nightmare unless you have a highly popular device globally... More people are working on the same thing..

Comment: Can you please refer me to someplace I can find some more info on this. I have been googling this for a while but without success.

Comment: Based on information from Intel Flash Tool & Other similar programs... https://www.needrom.com/download/intel-phone-flash-tool/  ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As far as I can tell this tool only flashes **TO** the device I'm looking for a tool that can download **FROM** the device.

Comment: Have you considered manually pulling the firmware through ADB, Root access or a custom recovery... If you can manage to install a custom recovery, then you can just try to find a stock recovery to complete the backup... You can convert the backup's made by custom recoveries into compatible ones..

Comment: @Zillinium I don't have root (That the reason I want to pull the ROM from the device - to get root). I haven't found a custom recovery for this device that works. Would you know where I can find one? =Can I pull the the files with ADB without root?