# Can't flash a recovery image on device with red state

Tags: boot-loop

noob here. I cant flash a recovery image on my Tecno Camon 12 phone. Its in a boot loop showing red state error and cant get past the logo. Trying to flash it with sp flash tool doesn't work since it cant detect the phone.

Comment: unlock bootloader first

Comment: How do I unlock the bootloader?

Comment: follow the unbrick guide first. when your phone is working again, enable oem unlocking in developer options (required for unlocking from fastboot) https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-31989.html

Comment: https://www.getdroidtips.com/download-tecno-flash-tool or https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-smart-phone-flash-tool will both work only when installed [MT67xx VCOM **preloader** drivers](https://www.androidblog.gs/download-mediatek-usb-vcom-drivers-latest/#MT67_Series_MT67xx_Helio) while phone is connected completely powered-off

Comment: The problem is that the device cannot be recognized by my pc for flashing.

Comment: i don't believe that. that would mean physical damage of usb jack. are you sure you doing it right? make sure device is powered-off completely (remove battery if possible). on windows 10 disable driver signature verification. open windows device manager and see what is happening when usb cable is connected. preloader is just visible for ~ 1 second. within this time, pick up the yellow triangle and install preloader driver (different from adb drivers). here is example [video](https://youtu.be/O2XWTAYmNUo)

Comment: i recommend to do a readback first (see step 11+12) before trying to flash anything. also it is good idea to create your own scatter file based on your current ROM. it is a good exercise to learn how flash tools work, and good to have a backup before flashing anything. Remember these golden rules: 1) Do **never** flash preloader  2) Always flash in ***'Download only'*** mode only 3) use **only** scatter file matching your exact device model + ROM version + partition layout
 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203283