# xiaomi redmi note 8T is stuck in recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, usb-debugging, reboot, loopback

My sister´s phone Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro is stuck in the recovery loop. it went in the recovery loop and kept on rebooting again and again. If I select "reboot to system," then it gets back to recovery mode again. I try the option connect with MIAssistant but I recognize that she does not have unable USB sharing, so that´s why I cannot connect that phone to app Mi PC Suite via USB...
Is there any chance to save her images, contacts... because she does not save it on the cloud nor do she save them to Google Drive or any other file host, she only save them on the local drive on mobile.
Thank you for any answers :)

Comment: What was the cause of this? Did you update MIUI? I doubt data can be recovered, only hope is trying to fix boot-loop

Comment: Not sure if of any help but worth a try, if you can get signed secure boot download agent with proper [auth_sv5.auth](https://github.com/AgentFabulous/xiaomi_mtk_brom_experiments) file, you could at least preserve status quo before doing experiments (you can't access userdata directly because of encryption) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203283

Comment: I try to describe what was she doing. So she increase the volume and the icon of volume (icon where you can see  volume level) did not disappear after a few seconds and when she turn on the facebook or insta this icon still does not disappear, So she turn off the phone by pressing the button on the right. 
And she turned it on again but the icon still was there, so she decided to restart her phone, and so she managed to get into recovery mode...

Comment: wait.. so this is not a boot-loop. only the volume button stucks/is wet/short-circuited. just let it dry it will work again after few weeks. if you manage to enter fastboot mode `fastboot continue` will boot ignoring Volume Up Button

Comment: yeah, but I am still in recovery mode. And i did not know how to get out of here. I try to reboot it but the phone turn off and when it turn on I was there again ...

Comment: https://www.hardreset.info/devices/xiaomi/xiaomi-redmi-note-8-pro/fastboot-mode

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1669444