# Cloned Galaxy S20U? Will it function?

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, mediatek

Bought what I thought was a Galaxy S20 Ultra, but not so. Will it work?

My SIM works as far as phone and text but the internet doesn't work. WiFi is on and it's all fine.

- IMEI says Apple iPad 10 Pro
- Zankyo Maxpad 10 is what my Google account identifies
- Build number: H_X25_S20U_20200523
- Custom build version: alps-mp-m0.mp1-V2.39_hy6580.weg.m_P96

Can I root this device?

Some device info and specs

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: The whole device is a fake, Android 10 was release in 2019, but the security patch level dates 2017. Also the navigation icons look like a much older Android version (something like Android 5/6). I would not use such a device at all. return it and claim your money back. If that is not possible learn from it as your money is gone and the device is crap.

Comment: @Robert if the API level doesn't lie, you may be right that it's [Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0). (Interestingly, the OP did tag this question with [tag:6.0-marshmallow]?)

Comment: It is MediaTek device, you should be able to dump `boot.img` off the device with [SP Flash Tool](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203283) and root with [Magisk](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/systemless-root/info) as usual

Comment: Will rooting be a benefit and how can I .. Been trying. No pc

Comment: Will rooting be a benefit and how can I .. Been trying. No pc

Comment: *"internet doesn't work"* is too broad. can be a problem with IMEI, mac address, DNS, APN settings, browser app, certificates, hosts file, etc. broken modem cannot fixed with root