# I'm looking for the scatter file for MT6771v/c

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-rom

I'm looking to flash a stock ROM onto my phone but the SP Flash tool says it's invalid. My phone's chip is MT6771V/C. My phone is currently on Android 10.

The internet ([this link, for example](https://romprovider.com/download-mediatek-scatter-files/)) has scatter files named MT6771T_Android_scatter, MT6771_Android_scatter 8.1 and MT6771_Android_scatter 9.0 and I'm not sure which one to use.

I tried making a scatter file using the MTK droid tools but the only that showed up when I clicked on the "Block Map" button is `[1, bmtpool, 0000000000, 0000000000, 0]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backup/dump kernel image (and full ROM) without root for Mediatek Devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203283/backup-dump-kernel-image-and-full-rom-without-root-for-mediatek-devices)

Comment: MTK droid tools is outdated, use Wwr_MTK