# How to factory reset when /data cannot be mounted?

Tags: factory-reset, encryption

My phone shows "Encryption unsuccessful" message after trying to open and the "Factory reset" button below it does nothing. I tried to boot into recovery mode (Power + Volume Up + Home) and chose "wipe data / factory reset", but it results in messages like this:

```
- wiping data..
- failed to mount /data
- wipe complete
```

Although it feels like the wipe is not complete, since the same errors keep happening..

I wonder if I should (if it is even possible) connect the phone to my PC with a USB cable and manually delete everything? Other than that, I'm not sure how to do a factory reset. Assuming this is not a hardware failure of course..

My phone is not rooted, and I don't care about data loss. I just want a way to reformat and be able to use the phone..

Edit: If possible, I would prefer to format the phone so that it does not encrypt the file system anymore, in order to prevent a future error of the same kind.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure, what that is :) The phone is not rooted. I just want to factory reset it. I can install ADB to my PC, I guess, if that's necessary. Although I prefer to do it with a built-in Ubuntu tool like `dd` or something if it's possible.

**Edit:** the device is 5ish years old i think, and it has been turned off for a while so it might have caused hardware issues. It got stuck while trying to open and I removed the battery, maybe that's what caused the encryption issue.

I could try Odin, I guess.. Not sure how to check the bootloader..

Comment: Sure, it wasn't a great device to begin with so I don't have my hopes up :p Just trying to see if it's saveable.. OK, I will try Odin. Thank you so much! I wish I could upvote your comments, though at this point, they are as good as any answer.. So you might want to post an answer :)

Comment: Will Odin root my phone? I don't really want to root it unless it's absolutely necessary. **Edit:** That's OK, I could work with another encrypted installation, if it works :p

Comment: I guess. The phone is not a Samsung, I actually doubt if i can even find its model since I cannot open the phone :) Wish there was a way to backup/restore the current firmware..

Comment: Connecting the phone to PC, Windows started downloading MT65XX drivers but I'm not sure what the XX part is..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backup/dump kernel image (and full ROM) without root for Mediatek Devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203283/backup-dump-kernel-image-and-full-rom-without-root-for-mediatek-devices)

Comment: I found that the phone model is MT6572. Phone brand is ZTE but I'm not sure about that.. I'm trying to find a stock rom for MT6572 now.. I think I need to use SP Flash Tool for this phone. The recovery screen looks very similar to this one: https://forums.androidcentral.com/attachments/general-help-how/84075d1380718778t-android-recovery-3e-3e.jpg

Comment: Mine doesn't show that. it just says "Android system recovery <3e>" then "Volume up/down to move.."

Comment: you can enter bootloader mode, install bootloader interface drivers and type *'fastboot getvar all'*

Comment: could be ZTE Blade with unlocked bootloader - *'fastboot format:ext4 userdata'* should work. or create your own scatter file with [Wwr_MTK](https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-21970.html) and format userdata from [SP Flash Tool](https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-21638.html)

Comment: how/where do i enter that command? thanks by the way :)

Comment: enter [bootloader](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/zte/zte-blade-l5/fastboot-mode) mode, install [Android Bootloader Interface](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb) drivers, download [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) and type *'fastboot devices'* in `cmd.exe`