# yestel x7 - boot loop - flash

Tags: boot-loop, 9.0-pie

I am trying to solve a boot loop problem on YesTel x7 running on Android 9. I did factory reset but that didn't help it is still stuck. I want to flash the system as a last resort. I have never done it before. Following tutorials I installed SP Flash Tool Download and mediatek-preloader-usb-vcom-drivers  I was trying to find firmaware for that model, but couldn't find any apk file.

**Does the flush have to be done with corresponding to the model apk file or can it be done with some sort of universal apk?**

Comment: downloaded apk is scam/malware for sure. ROM never is apk file. you can read ROM from device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backup/dump kernel image (and full ROM) without root for Mediatek Devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203283/backup-dump-kernel-image-and-full-rom-without-root-for-mediatek-devices)

Comment: You could try to contact customer support, but their website looks ancient http://www.yestel.mobi heyunshanyx@hotmail.com